# Не понимаю почему не проходят тесты задачи?

Tags: javascript

> Count the number of Duplicates
>   Write a function that will return the count of distinct case-insensitive alphabetic characters and numeric digits that occur more than once in the input string. The input string can be assumed to contain only alphabets (both uppercase and lowercase) and numeric digits.

Вот [задача](https://www.codewars.com/kata/counting-duplicates/train/javascript)

Вот моё решение:

```js
function duplicateCount(text){
  if(text.length!=0){
    var count=0, j,myreg;
    text=text.toLowerCase();
    for(let i=0;i<text.length;i++){
      myreg= new RegExp(text[i],'gi');
      if(text.match(myreg).length>=2){
        count++;
        text = text.replace(myreg,'');
      }
    }
    return count;
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Я понял задачу так: если встречаться символ более одного раза увеличиваем счётчик. В результате вывести счётчик.

Comment: Приведите текст задачи в вопросе. На русском языке. Это русскоязычный ресурс)

Comment: @doox911 вообще-то тесты проходят. Правда реализация с помощью регулярок..ну такое

Comment: Наверно из-за регулярки - по скорости не проходят, а вообще проходят.

Comment: @DreamChild значит, это плохие тесты (

Comment: @DreamChild Проходят но не все.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать автору теста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, для коллекции:

```
function duplicateCount(text){
   let t = text.toLowerCase();
   let s = new Set();
   let dup = new Set();
   for (let c of t) {
     if (s.has(c)) dup.add(c);
     s.add(c);
  }
   return dup.size;
}
```

Comment: Очень понравилось ваше решение.

Answer (score 2):

```
  ...
  text = text.replace(myreg,'');
  i--;
}
...
```

Тест:

```
Test.assertEquals(duplicateCount("abbFcccFde"), 3);
```

Без `i--;` сначала пропускается первая `F` при удалении `b`, а потом - вторая при удалении `c`.

```js
function duplicateCount(text, expected){
  var result = 0;

  var counts = {};
  var textL = text.toLowerCase();
  for(var i = 0; i < textL.length; i++) {
    var currentCount = (counts[textL[i]] || 0) + 1;
    counts[textL[i]] = currentCount;
    if (currentCount == 2)
      result++;
  }

  console.log(`result = ${result}, expected = ${expected}`, 
    (result == expected)? "passed" : "failed", text);
  return result;
}

duplicateCount("", 0);
duplicateCount("abcde", 0);
duplicateCount("aabbcde", 2);
duplicateCount("aabBcde", 2,"should ignore case");
duplicateCount("Indivisibility", 1);
duplicateCount("Indivisibilities", 2, "characters may not be adjacent");

duplicateCount('abcabc', 3);
duplicateCount("abbFcccFde", 3);
duplicateCount('bbb', 1);
```

Comment: Не обязательно на один уменьшить. Может быть строчка `ibiiiii`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Добавил.